# How do I determine whether a node is present when Transforming Xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I determine whether a given node is present in my input xml?

If the node is present I would like to use the value of `reportAuthor1`, but otherwise I would use the value of `reportAuthor`. I have tried unsuccessfully to use if and else.

```
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="reportAuthor1=''">
 <xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor1"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `not()` to check whether a node doesn't exist at all:

```
<xsl:choose>  
  <xsl:when test="not(reportAuthor1)">  
    <xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor"/>
  </xsl:when>  
  <xsl:otherwise>  
    <xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor1"/>  
  </xsl:otherwise>  
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is probably the simplest and shortest, one-line XPath expression. Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor1 | reportAuthor[not(reportAuthor1)]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you may also write

```
<xsl:value-of select="reportAuthor1 | reportAuthor"/>
```

`|` returns the union of sets returned by the XPath queries from the left and from the right side of this operator, and `<xsl:value-of select="somequery"/>` will send to the output the value of the first node in the set returned by somequery. Thus, if both `reportAuthor1` and `reportAuthor` are set, it'll output the value of `reportAuthor1`; if only `reportAuthor` is set, it'll output the value of `reportOutput`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I have tried the previous solution .Il try this also.

Comment: Aaah, my comment got screwed up by parser originally, one must not forget the blank line! My code example is similar to Dimitre Novatchev answer, despite being slower (`reportAuthor` will be calculated even if there is a `reportAuthor1`). From the other side, XSLT processor should be smart enough not to calculate `reportAuthor` in such a situation.

Comment: One issue with using the union operator rather than `<xsl:choose>` is that it selects whichever comes first in the XML, so if a `reportAuthor` element preceded a `reportAuthor1`, it would use that, even though `reportAuthor1` is first in the select clause. You can mitigate this with `reportAuthor1 | reportAuthor[not(../reportAuthor1)]`, which will only select a `reportAuthor` element if it doesn't have a `reportAuthor1` sibling (the xpath specifies that it's parent doesn't have a `reportAuthor1` child).

Comment: @Flynn1179 You're absolutely right. I didn't know of this not so obvious feature of unions. This makes my answer incorrect, and Dimitre Novatchev's answer the only correct one with the union operator.

Comment: Actually, Dimitre's is wrong, it would select `reportAuthor` elements that don't have a `reportAuthor1` CHILD. The `../` in my suggested fix is important.